# Mapping defined via quadratic forms is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis

Let $V$ be a two dimensional normed $\mathbb{R}$ vector space and $f, g:V\to\mathbb{R}$ be two quadratic forms. Is it true that the function $$H:V\to \mathbb{R}^{2}$$ with $$H(x)=(f(x), g(x))$$ is continuous? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here's a simpler question: is a quadratic form continuous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a quadratic form is continuous (why?), and the mappings $x\mapsto (x,0)$
$x\mapsto (0,x)$ are, continuous, as well, the composition is also continuous.

Comment: Actually, I don't see how the diagonal mapping $x \mapsto (x,x)$ is helpful in this context. The inclusion mappings $x \mapsto (x,0)$ and $x \mapsto (0,x)$ seem more relevant.

Comment: @peek-a-boo you are right, thanks. I have answered in a hurry, which I should not do.

Comment: Can one also argument, that since quadratic forms are continuous, $H$ is continuous in both components and hence, continuous?

Comment: @ShaqAttack1337 yes, that's right. The purpose of suggesting these inclusion maps (let me call them $\iota_1$ and $\iota_2$) is to prove that "if both components of $H$ are continuous, then $H$ is continuous". Because notice that $\iota_1, \iota_2$ are clearly continuous, and that we can write $H = \iota_1 \circ f + \iota_2 \circ g$, i.e we have expressed $H$ as a sum of a composition of continuous functions. Hence, $H$ is continuous. But of course, if you already know this theorem, then you can just invoke it without any further proof.